# TCP/UDP list in command line

Tags: command-line, networking

I would like to know if exits some software or guide list I don't know the correct term, that I can access by terminal and inform me all about that specifies port.

Exemple: I using `nmap` and I would like to know `What is port 680/tcp`, but I don't want to access this information by browser, I want to use the terminal, like `root@root:/home# guide tcp 680` that would return me the information.. Please that command is unrealistic!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lsof` (you may have to `sudo apt-get install lsof`) will show you which process has port 680 open, thusly:

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:680
```

On my system (and looking at port 22, because I have nothing listening to port 680) the result is:

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:22
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    4063 root    3u  IPv4  20684      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    4063 root    4u  IPv6  20686      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
```

Be sure to read `man lsof` (in general, whenever some "helpful" stranger tells you to `sudo *anything*`, be sure to read `man *anything*`).